# Should + not difference

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference, modal-verbs, sentence-structure, word-difference

What is the exact difference in meaning between:

- Should there not be a sign here?
- Should not there be a sign here?
- Should there be not a sign here?

My research tells me that:

- 1st - There could be a sign here, but nobody put one.
- 2nd - There should be a sign here, but nobody put one.
- 3rd - There are or is a sign here while there shouldn't be any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is gramatically correct but sounds rather odd. I don't know how you've arrived at the conclusion that "should" means "could" though. The meaning is exactly the same as example (2).

(2) means what your research tells you. However, questions of this type are usually written and spoken using the contraction "shouldn't", i.e.

> *Shouldn't there be a sign here?*

(3) is just wrong. To get the meaning that you've indicated, that there is a sign where there possibly shouldn't be one you would say:

> *Is this sign supposed/meant to be here?*

Comment: I disagree over "Is this sign supposed/meant to be here?" I think then it's better to say "Shouldn't there be no sign here?"

Comment: And yeh, thanks, I know about the contraction! I just didn't place in order to establish a clear view.

Comment: "Shouldn't there be no..." does make sense if you're really intent on using "should" but double negatives should generally be avoided as they are difficult to parse for the hearer/reader. Hence it's considered better style and more natural to frame the question positively.

Comment: I agree, but the double negative here makes everything clear. Example: "Shouldn't you not be at work today? I thought you were ill."

Comment: It might be clear to you because you wrote it and so you know what meaning was intended. It's not clear to others though; "Shouldn't you not be at work today?" sounds really strange as well. In fact, if I heard someone say that, I would think they had made a mistake, and meant to ask "Shouldn't you be at work today". I would recommend avoiding double negatives completely. I would rather say: *Shouldn't you be off work today?*

Comment: Yes, yes. Double negatives are really bad! What makes them bad as i think is that most people are afraid of them and can't use them.

Comment: I realise that in your native language, Russian, double negatives are widely used. However, that is not the case in English and you should accept that. Most English speakers upon hearing a double negative will consider it incorrect and potentially confusing.

Comment: I like articles which tell us that in some cases double negatives or a negative + an adjective or adverb with a negative prefix carry a specific meaning, especially in formal writing!

Comment: I suppose you mean examples like, to quote Tom Jones, "it's not unusual". But this is a different matter entirely from what your question was about so I'm not sure what relevance it has. I stick with everything I've said above and have no more to say on the matter. If you're unwilling to learn, I can't make you.

Comment: I agree. I'm not trying to compare Russian to English, that's absurd! But I noticed that in spoken English people sometimes use double negatives to emphasize something they wish to say! Or if they imply a special case like: Hadn't we not taken the papers from the office.He wouldn't have found them there!

Comment: you wouldn't say "hadn't we not taken...", you would say: *Had we not taken the papers from the office, he would have found them there.*

Comment: Yes, you are right!